# ontouchstart getting right result after resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question related to 'ontouchstart' in window.

I´m having this code

```
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    if('ontouchstart' in window){
      console.log("resize touch true")
    }else{
      console.log("resize touch false")
    }
  })
```

So working with Chrome. I load the Page and i get "resize touch false". 
Now set the Browser to iphone6 for example and load the page. Now the result is touch true. Everything right until here.

But, when i'm starting with iphone (log touch true) and switch to desktop i'm still getting "touch true" and vice versa.

I have to reload the page to get the right result.

Question: Can I get right result without reload the page?

Comment: Its an emulator you are trying from browser and by default you need to reload the page to see the changes. So I believe, this behavior is as expected..